# Using RX (Reactive Extensions) to create 20 events with 30 millisecond delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reactive

I want to make a quick burst fire code that would call me a function 20 times, at 30 millisecond intervals.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Observable.Repeat(20).Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30)).Subscribe()
```

That seemed like the logical solution to me, but my app is crashing, I assume its because it is not stopping ever.

Using UniRx how can I achieve this?
https://rx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want [`Observable.Interval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229027(v=vs.103).aspx) and [`Observable.Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229852%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30)).Take(20)
```

Furthermore, the methods you are using are not doing what you think they're doing.  You should read the documentation before just trying things.

- [`observable.Repeat(20)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.repeat(v=vs.103).aspx)  just repeatedly calls `observer.OnNext(20)` for each subscribed observer, forever.
- [`observable.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229810(v=vs.103).aspx) just time shifts the entire sequence to be 30 milliseconds later than it would have been otherwise.

Comment: Beat me to it, just had finished typing my answer when I saw yours!

Comment: Thank you. This is extremely useful. Kind of like the opposite of buffer.

Comment: Small OT correction: He shouldn't read the documentation before trying things, he should try things before posting questions that are easily answered by trying things. :)

Comment: is it possible to do this 

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30)).Take(20) 

over and over again ? for instance if i wanted to buffer a Stream in a way that i'm taking the next 20 every 30 ms ?